# Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type (conflict with CrudRepository)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data

I have an HTML page with a text field and a button.

When I fill the field and click enter I get the following error.

Failed to convert value of type  `'java.lang.String' to required type '...model.Test'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException:` Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Integer] for value 'typedvaluehere'

The code is below.

One interesting thing I noted is that when I remove `extends CrudRepository<Test, Integer>` from the repository, the error stops happening. But I can't do that, because I need it. But shows it seems to be a conflict with CrudRepository.

Another interesting thing I noted is that if I change `private String test` in the model to something else such as `private String name` and update getters/setters, it will work fine. Even with the CrudRepository. Seems it doesn't allow a field that has the same name of the model class name.

The complete project is available for download at:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qfn73uGH6eUmJf8vtWZvbSn2IQiI0MzB/view?usp=sharing

**AddTest.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="addtest" method="post">
<input type="text" name="test"/>
<input type="submit" name="btnAddTest" value="Add">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Controller**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addtest", params = "btnAddTest", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView addTest(@ModelAttribute Test test) {

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("AddTest.html");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

**Model**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Tests")
public class Test implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int idTest;
        
    @Column(length=100)
    private String test;

    public int getIdTest() {
        return idTest;
    }

    public void setIdTest(int idTest) {
        this.idTest = idTest;
    }

    public String getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void setTest(String test) {
        this.test = test;
    }   
        
}
```

**Repository**

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public interface TestRepository extends CrudRepository<Test, Integer>{
    
}
```

Comment: can you show us the the html form?

Comment: Hi @Aman. I just updated the question adding the complete html per your request. It's pretty much just the input and button that I posted before. But added the rest also.

Comment: @Aman, I also added the project link for download in the question above.

Comment: Check https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-form-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED:

Try updating your form as follows:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
...
<form:form  action="addtest" method="post" modelAttribute="test">
    <form:input type="text" name="test"/>
    <form:input type="submit" name="btnAddTest" value="Add"/>
</form:form >
```

Or since you have added thymleaf, try the following:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/addtest}" th:object="${test}" method="post">
    <input type="text" th:field="*{test}" />
   <input type="submit" name="btnAddTest" value="Add">
</form>


@RequestMapping(value = "/addtest", params = "btnAddTest", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addTest(@ModelAttribute Test test, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        //errors processing
    }  
    model.addAttribute("test", new Test());

   return "AddTest";
}
```

Comment: It didn't work. Did not recognize modelAttribute="Test" in the form tag.

Comment: I tried the thymeleaf option as I'm using that with html, not jsp. It doesn't open the form page. It shows the following error:
Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'test' available as request attribute

Comment: @jkfe it is strange, I have also added the Controller method body. this should definitely work.

Comment: did you dowload the project I provided and executed on your machine?

Comment: I'm on java 11.